# How to install the new Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I have downloaded the stable version of Android Studio 2.0, it's just an archive with files. How can I install it and should I delete my old version of Android Studio before installation the new version ?

My OS is Windows 10 64bit

Comment: When you downloaded it, did your browser not redirect you to [the installation instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have downloaded the stable version of Android Studio 2.0, it's just an archive with files.

Just unpack the archive wherever you want or download stable version with installer as listed in the table on the bottom of official page: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html